# Doctrine inheritance

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine

I am trying to model something that it is posible in php classes but i dont know how to make the association in Doctrine and maybe it is not possible and crazy...

I have 2 classes which inheritance from same class and one main class that can contain both of them, so it contain the main one. In this one i can add different types of components easyly.

```
public class Main {
    /** @var GlobalClass */
    private $components;
}
abstract public GlobalClass {
    /* ... Some code here ... */
}
public Class1 extends GlobalClass {
    /* ... Some code here ... */
}
public Class2 extends GlobalClass {
    /* ... Some code here ... */
}
```

Class1 and Class2 share several attributes but not everyone, so i think they are two different entities to Doctrine, so I have mapped GlobalClass as a mappedSuperclass

```
App\Domain\Model\GlobalClass:
    type: mappedSuperclass
    table: global
    id:
            id:
                type: string
                generator:
                strategy: UUID
    fields:
            name:
                type: string
                length: 100
```

And the other two classes:

```
App\Domain\Model\Class1:
    type: entity
    table: class1
    repositoryClass: Infrastructure\Persistence\Doctrine\Class1Repo
    fields:
            url:
                    type: string
                    nullable: true

manyToOne:
    main:
        targetEntity: App\Domain\Model\Main
        inversedBy: component
        joinColumn:
            nullable: true
```

But what to write in the mapping of Main class? That is my question.

Without the manyToOne relationship everything worked and generated correctly the schema. But now, How do i tell doctrine that $components can be from class1 table add class2

It is may be imposible, I am doing it in some other way to walkaround the problem but... i wonder if someone has deal with this.

Thank you very much in advance!

P.D. I guess this will be easier in Mongo, but i need Doctrien ORM and MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of mapped superclass you should use in this situation Class table inheritance or Single table inheritance (depends which suit more your schema / expectations - https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance).

Then you actually do ManyToOne from your Main to GlobalClass and doctrine will return collection where will be both Class1 and Class2 (depends what was saved).

Comment: I am reading the doc of Single table inheritance and i am not using that because  i will add more type of components in future  so as it is writen there, it has an adverse impact. But thanks!

Comment: If you add more different components in future, then class table inheritance is the way to go.

Comment: At the end I've use class table inheritance! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i was wondering all the time yesterday night, i guess i should have rest before and think about it before posting this...

But at the moment it is something I already have but i dont know why i didnt do it... sorry. I write the answer so someone can use it.

```
App\Domain\Model\Main:
type: entity
table: main
repositoryClass: Infrastructure\Persistence\Doctrine\MainRepo
id:
    id:
        type: string
        generator:
        strategy: UUID
fields:
    status:
        type: integer

oneToMany:
    components:
        targetEntity: App\Domain\Model\GlobalClass
        mappedBy: global
```

Anyway if this is not a good aproach I will like to know :D thanks.